# calling a method in which way?

Tags: java

I want to make connection between two parts of my program which can be located in departed places.
I have some choices for making this connection:

1. using PRC/RMI: in every request a calling method will send to second part
2. using normal function call
3. using queue(in memory):every request will be placed in a queue and second part will get that and answer requests
4. using queue(in DB):like number 3 but in DB
5. using socket for sending data(TCP/IP or UDP or ...)
6. using web service

can anyone compare these available ways?

Comment: Are the application parts always on the same server or on different servers, client - server?

Comment: "departed places" sounds like you want to communicate with the dead. You mean "separate" places, as in different hosts?

Comment: Not sure what happened to the image you posted, but it obviously no longer relates to the question. I edited it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

1. RPC/RMI - Requires the RMI/IIOP protocol over the wire, which limits you to using Java for both the client and the server.
2. Normal function call means both objects are resident in the same JVM and cannot be distributed.  This will be the fastest option for a single method call.  Reusing that object means having to package it in a JAR and redistribute it to all the other apps that need it.  Now you've got to know where all those JARs are if the code changes.  Distribution is an issue.
3. Asynchronous processing, but you'll have to write all the queue and handling code.  This would take strong multi-threading skills.  Could be very fastest of all, because it's all in memory and would allow parallel processing if you had multiple cores.  It's also the most dangerous, because you have to be thread-safe.
4. Don't understand why you'd have the queue in a database.  I'd prefer a Java EE app server for doing this.  Not all RDBMS have queues running inside them.  If you agree and go with JMS, this will be asynchronous and distributed and robust.  It'll allow topics or queues, which can be flexible.  But it'll be slower than the others.
5. Using a socket is just like RMI, except you have to write the entire protocol.  Lots of work.
6. A web service will be similar to RMI in performance.  But it'll use HTTP as the protocol, which means that any client that can formulate an HTTP request can call it.  REST or SOAP will give you flexibility about message choices (e.g., XML, JSON, etc.)

Synchronous calls mean the caller and callee are directly coupled.  The interface has to be kept constant.

Asynchronous calls mean looser coupling between the caller and callee.  Like the synchronous case, the messages have to be relatively stable.

UPDATE: The picture you added makes the problem murkier.  The interaction with 3rd party merchant and card handlers makes your error situation dicier.  What happens if one of those fails?  What if either one is unavailable?  If the bank fails, how do you communicate that back to the 3rd parties?  Very complicated, indeed.  You'll have bigger problems than just choosing between RMI and web services.

Comment: Re 4: I work near a project that uses a DB for communicating between 2 apps. It's dirty, it's ugly, it's a hack, but it works reliably and performs well - in production for about 10 years now.

Comment: @Carl - no doubt it works.  The OP specifically mentioned a queue, which made me think s/he wanted Java running inside.  The only problem I have with this working solution is that it unnecessarily couples two apps at the database level.  Change the database and two apps have to change.  I know it's commonly done, but it's one source of coupling that I don't like.  I would prefer to see a more service-oriented approach, where a service owns its data and provides an interface to it.  That has its own trade-offs, of course.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Coupling thru the DB may be a highly pragmatic solution but I wouldn't recommend it without more analysis. In fact, for a homework type problem, it would probably be best to not recommend it at all.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a lot to answer there. Briefly:

1. If your program is split up into a client/server, you can't use a normal method call.
2. Queuing would possibly work if your method calls are *one-way* (have no return value). However if you want to return values synchronously then what do you do ? Have two queues - one for outgoing and one for incoming results ? And what do you do re. exceptions. It's not a natural fit.
3. Web services will work. However they're often used for bridging between client/servers on different platforms and written in different languages, so it may be a lot of unnecessary work here. The same applies to CORBA, btw.
4. A TCP socket solution would work, but requires quite a lot of extra work to set up (if you want to invoke separate methods etc.). Note (also) that TCP and UDP are fundamentally different and for reliability purposes I wouldn't use UDP normally for this sort of stuff.
5. RMI is pretty straightforward to set up in Java, and that would probably be a good first step. Check out [the RMI tutorial here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Option (2) will only work if both parts of your program are running in the same JVM.

Options (3) and (4) only work if you don't mind the calls being asynchronous, i.e. not returning a result directly to the caller.

Options (5) and (6) take a lot of work to set up, you'd be better off with (1).